# Detect Apache version in apache config?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**tl;dr:** How do I do the following in a .conf or .htaccess file:

```
<IfApache22>
  # Do A
</IfApache22>
<IfApache24>
  # Do B
</IfApache24>
```

**Longer question:**

With Apache 2.4 the old [Order](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) get's deprecated in favor of [Require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require).

In my .htaccess files I have

```
<FilesMatch "\.(long|list|file|types)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

which means Apache fails to start unless I enable [access_compat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html). While doing so presents a useful workaround, I want a solution that works with both syntaxes as the config will be distributed to a lot of servers. The question is how I can detect the current version of Apache and apply the correct directive.

I intend to use the file for a framework that is distributed to and used by a lot of people, and I can't control/guarantee that they have or lack any particular server setup, which is why I'd like the file to be 2.2/2.4 "agnostic".

Answer (score 33):

A hack that I have used.

```
# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Satisfy Any
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all granted
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ...or if that module is absent on both ends, but your local/stage server is win (and Apache 2.x) and your live is linux (and Apache 2.y), check for any other module difference, i.e. `<IfModule !mod_win32.c>`

Comment: fantastic answer.  Everything seems to build for 2.4, but mine is 2.2, this allows forward compatibility!

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you have [mod_version](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_version.html) installed (many distributions ship it by default) you can do the following:

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    # Require ...
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    # Order ...
    # Deny ...
    # Allow ...
</IfVersion>
```

Comment: I recommend this answer. If you can afford the extra dependency this approach is much clearer. Also, if mod_authz_core is ever disabled when using the approach in the accepted answer then the config file will assume it is running on 2.2 and continue regardless. Removing mod_version here will simply mean the server will refuse to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can run different versions of Apache on the same host. Q: What's wrong with separate config files in separate directories? I honestly believe that's probably the cleanest approach...

Nevertheless, Apache .conf files allow an `<IfDefine>`, which you can specify at runtime with "-D":

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#ifdefine

Comment: +1 for the IfDefine and -D option. It doesn't really help me though. Running two versions of the webserver seems like _a lot_ of work when a simple if/else should be able to solve it. Can you expand "separate directories" a bit more? Checking the current version seems like a very nice solution to me. Expanded the question a bit on why.

Answer (score 1):

You could bypass the need to know by using mod_rewrite for your access control:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(long|list|file|types)$
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem because FallbackResource is not in early versions of Apache and often clever hosting companies remove mod_rewrite once they have a version of Apache with FallbackResource.  I use the following .htaccess when I want to put library code up that adapts to its environment:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    FallbackResource index.php
</IfModule>
```

Now of course there are some Apache versions / setups where this fails - but if mod_rewrite is there, use it and if not, hope that FallbackResource is there.