# How to set Apache conditional header based on URL?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, if-statement, header

I want to set different HTTP header depending on the URL. In my particular case I want a specific URL (e.g. regex `^/abc$`) to have a different header than all the rest.

I am trying this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /^\/abc$/">
        Header set Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
    </If>
    <Else>
        Header set Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'none'; child-src https: *.youtube.com 'self'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src https: *.ytimg.com *.youtube.com 'self'; style-src 'self';"
    </Else>
</IfModule>
```

However this doesn't seem to work, the log says:

```
Cannot parse condition clause: Failed to compile regular expression
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this to work?

I also tried the alternate regex form `m#^/abc$#` and then there is no error but there is no match for the If condition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `If` condition like this to evaluate regular expression:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/abc/?$#">
```

---

**EDIT:** On Apache 2.4+ following works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#\s/+abc/?[?\s]#">
        Header set Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
    </If>
    <Else>
        Header set Content-Security-Policy: "default-src 'none'; child-src https: *.youtube.com 'self'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src https: *.ytimg.com *.youtube.com 'self'; style-src 'self';"
    </Else>
</IfModule>
```

If you are on older Apache then use this `mod_rewrite` trick:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+abc/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYENV1:1]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+abc/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYENV2:1]

Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" env=MYENV1
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; child-src https: *.youtube.com 'self'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src https: *.ytimg.com *.youtube.com 'self'; style-src 'self';" env=MYENV2
```

Comment: ok use `THE_REQUEST` variable in that case. See my updated answer.

Comment: So what is the solution for Apache 2.2?

Comment: Great. Thank you. Last question: Is it possible to combine both things in one, so that there is automatic recognition of the proper Apache version and based on that - to have either the 2.4 solution or the one for older versions?

Comment: [See answers in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707186/detect-apache-version-in-apache-config)

Comment: @anubhava On your edit for 2.4 can you explain why the syntax changed? why the `\s` in place of the `^` etc?

Comment: Actually syntax hasn't changed. I used `THE_REQUEST` which starts with `GET|PUT|POST|HEAD` etc followed by a space and then the actual URL. In 2nd block I am matching space and then the URL.

Answer (score 5):

This is a one-line alternative taken from [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header):

```
Header always set CustomHeader my-value "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/special_path.php$#"
```

Comment: The landmine here is if more than one of these match, as opposed to the if/else proposed in anubhava's answer