# How to set HTTP header difference by URL in Apache

Tags: regex, apache, docker, if-statement, header

I try to set Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) (via docker) form this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791279/how-to-set-apache-conditional-header-based-on-url) but that's not work for me.

Configuration file like.

```
  Header set Test-1 %{THE_REQUEST}e
  <If "%{REQUEST_URI} != '/en'">
    Header set Test-2 %{REQUEST_URI}e
  </If>
```

When call GET /en HTTP header is

```
  Test-1: (null)
  Test-2: /en
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%{REQUEST_URI}e` instead of `%{THE_REQUEST}e`.

You can also simplify this by using:

```
Header set Test-1 %{REQUEST_URI}e

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(?!en/?$)" NO_EN
Header set Test-2 %{REQUEST_URI}e env=NO_EN
```

Comment: No, any url have HTTP's header Test-2. I think Request_URI in expression is allway null.

Comment: I have tested this fully before posting. Test with only these 3 lines in your .htaccess and remove everything else. When I send URL as `/en` then only `Test-1` was returned. For all other URIs both `Test-1` and `Test-2` were returned. btw `%{REQUEST_URI}` is working for me on a production website

Comment: My environments is in docker. I don't know if it's affect this or not. <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == 'something'"> can't get value but  %{REQUEST_URI}e does.

Comment: Your code is not work for me. I guess in my environment SetEnvIf can't Request_URI too.

Comment: Thing is we don't even know what kind of web server is inside the container. To test you can copy these 3 lines in an .htaccess on your localhost and verify.