# Conditional header with .htaccess works on HTML but not on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-headers

I am not a developer, but need to maintain my own website. The website is available in three languages. The homepage for each language is:

`/   Portuguese
/es/ Spanish
/en/ English`

I want to set a header that would go to these three URIs, but not to other pages on the site. I came up with a group of rules for setting conditional headers that work fine on a HTML test site, but not on WordPress:

```
# All pages
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^(.*)$" REQUEST_URI=$1
Header set a-URI "%{REQUEST_URI}e"
# Conditional headers
# Is homepage?
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/$" is_homepage
Header set aa-homepage "Yes" env=is_homepage
Header set aa-homepage "No" env=!is_homepage
# Is homepage OR either /es/ or /en/ subdir
SetEnvIf Request_URI /(es/|en/)?$ is_home_dir
Header set aa-homepage_dir "Yes" env=is_home_dir
Header set aa-homepage_dir "No" env=!is_home_dir
# Is either /es/ or /en/?
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^(es|en)$/" is_es_en
Header set aa-dir_es_en "Yes" env=is_es_en
Header set aa-dir_es_en "No" env=!is_es_en
```

When I visit `/` on my WordPress website, I get the following headers:

```
a-uri: /
aa-dir_es_en: No
aa-homepage: Yes
aa-homepage_dir: Yes
```

It correctly interprets the rule for the `aa-homepage_dir` header. But when I go to `/es/`, I get this:

```
a-uri: /es/
aa-dir_es_en: No
aa-homepage: No
aa-homepage_dir: No
```

Though the REQUEST_URI is being correctly reported as `/es/`, it is not being matched on the WordPress website by the regular expression for the `aa-dir_es_en` and `aa-homepage_dir` headers.

I'd appreciate if anyone could point my error in making this work. BTW, I've tried these rules both before and after the WordPress basic .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this puzzle by using THE_REQUEST instead of REQUEST_URI:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#\s/+(/?|en/?|es/?)[?\s]#"> 
Header set CustomHeader "header value"
</If>
```

Thanks to [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) for providing this answer to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791714/8183887

I still have no idea why REQUEST_URI wouldn't work in this situation, but at least I have my conditional header working.