# Access-Control-Allow-Origin: Access for all users just to one site

Tags: javascript, php, json, apache, server

I'm currently coding a php website which reads certain values from a json file from my server.
Now when i request the xmlhttp request to my server, i get the Access-control-allow-origin ERROR in console. I already find out i have to set Access-control-allow-origin: *; in my Apache configuration but i don't want to use * because I don't want to give everyone access to my website. So how can i just give permission for one json file to every client?

```
var requestURL = 'https://myWebsite/blabla.json';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  var response = request.response;
  jackpot = response.items[0].value;

  var inner = document.getElementById("myid");
inner.innerHTML = jackpot+" EURO";
```

this is my js code and i always get the Error, except i use Access-control-allow-origin: *, which i dont want to use because its unsave.

Please care im little new to web coding so im not really professional sorry.

Comment: Instead of the * you have to list the URL(s) (called "origins" in this context) which are allowed to make cross-domain requests to your server URL. Any web page loaded from one of those origins will then be able to make cross-domain requests. (Well, actually you might need some other headers too, it's not always that simple. [The CORS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) can give you more info.

Comment: Yes i know but I don't know yet which sites are going to include my script so I I need to give everyone access but only for this one json file and not for my hole website.

Comment: "but only for this one json file"...in that case you have to detect which URL is being requested, and only issue the access-control headers when that URL is being requested.

Comment: P.S. "I need to give everyone access" and "i don't want to use * because I don't want to give everyone access" directly contradict each other. Please make up your mind what you want to achieve. Either you want to give _everyone_ access to _one_ file, or you want to give _some sites_ access to _one or more_ files.

Comment: So where do I have to set the Access control allow origin property? In the php Script? I currently set it in the apache configuration. but is it also possible in the script?

Comment: i want to give everyone Acces to one site. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: you mean one file (i.e. one URL), not one whole site, I think?

Comment: Yeah sorry again :)

Comment: Since your file extension ends .json I don't think PHP is going to be involved, apache will be serving the file directly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791279/how-to-set-apache-conditional-header-based-on-url might help you

Comment: Aight I guess thats it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP backend, allow only to your domain for `Access-control-allow-origin` not `*`. So that it will be safe.

Comment: Yeah I already know that, but I don't know yet which sites are going to include this js script so I can't list them because I don't know them yet, so I want to give everyone access but only for this one json file not for the hole website.